# Iframe not working properly in express js

Tags: javascript, html, express

When Im using iframe in HTML, it works perfect:

`<iframe src="main.html" height="100px"></iframe>`

But in express when I use Iframe its showing error:

`<iframe src="main.html" height="100px"></iframe>`

[See Image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VeKV2.png)

It says " cannot GET /main.html "

iframe.js:

```
const express = require("express")

const app = express()


app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send(`<iframe src="main.html" height="100px"></iframe>`)
})

const port = 4000

app.listen(port)
console.log(`Example App Running at http://localhost:${port}`)
```

I know it can embed any directory, but i want it to work with my local filesystem

Is it possible that i can add local files like main.html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the browser asks for `/` then your server finds `app.get('/', (req, res) => {` and sends it some HTML.

This causes the browser to ask for `/main.html`, but you haven't told the server what to do then!

You need to write a handler for `/main.html`. This could be specific like the one you have for `/`. This could be generic, such as the [static middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) provides.